# Trouble with Serialization and Deserialization in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I'm working on a project right now where I implement Bellford's Algorithm on a series of different ports for my class.

I'm having a lot of trouble with what I believe is a serialization issue where I am sending my Vector_Table object over a UDP socket connection. I serialize the vector table first and then I receive an EOFException. I've done some work to narrow down the location of the bug and it seems to be in the receiving socket of the second 'router' constructed. When I get the bytes[] from the receiving UDPSocket and try and cast to a Vector_Table is where it comes from.

I am having a lot of trouble understanding why this is being thrown. The sending is working for the initially constructed router so I would think that the sending of these tables is working. I don't know why it would be different in this direction?

Any assitance would be greatly appreciated. I'm guessing it is a byte level issue, but am a little over my head.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    p P = new p();
    int listenPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    Vector_Table currentTable = new Vector_Table (Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, (args.length)));
    vTableReceiver receiverThread;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput obj = new ObjectOutputStream(bOut);
    try {
        obj.writeObject(currentTable);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentTable.bytesToTable(bOut.toByteArray());
    System.out.println("hey");

    //currentTable.printTable();
    try {
        receiverThread = new vTableReceiver(listenPort, currentTable);
        receiverThread.run();


public class vTableReceiver implements Runnable{

    p P = new p();
    boolean isRunning = true; 
    Vector_Table currentTable;
    Vector_Table received;
    byte[] buff = new byte[512];
    DatagramSocket socket;

    public vTableReceiver(int port, Vector_Table currTbl) throws SocketException {
        P.P("Receiver Constructed");
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        currentTable = currTbl;

    }

    public void stopThread(){ isRunning = false;}

    public void run() {
        P.P("Receiver Run started");
        try {currentTable.sendToNeighbors(socket);} 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(isRunning){
            try{

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                currentTable.reCalc(packet.getData(), socket.getInetAddress());
                currentTable.sendToNeighbors(socket);
                currentTable.printTable();}
            catch(SocketException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }   

    System.out.println("Thread over");
    }
}


public class Vector_Table implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<edge> linkList = new ArrayList<edge>();
    ArrayList<edge> neighborList = new ArrayList<edge>();

    public Vector_Table(String[] cmdLineInterfaces){
        for(int i = 0; i < cmdLineInterfaces.length; i++ ){
            linkList.add(new edge(cmdLineInterfaces[i]));
            neighborList.add(new edge(cmdLineInterfaces[i]));

        }
    }

    public void reCalc(byte[] newTable, InetAddress myAddr) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException{
        Vector_Table inTable = bytesToTable(newTable);
        int myWeight = 0;
        for(edge e : inTable.linkList){
            if (e.address == myAddr)
                myWeight = e.weight;}
        if(myWeight == 0){System.out.println("Didn't get weight??");}

        for(edge e : inTable.linkList){
            boolean found = false;
            for(edge e2 : linkList){
                if (e2.address == e.address)
                {
                    if (e.weight + myWeight < e2.weight)
                        e2.weight = (e.weight + myWeight);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                e.weight += myWeight;
                linkList.add(e);
            }
        }
    }



    void sendToNeighbors(DatagramSocket socket) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput obj = new ObjectOutputStream(bOut);
        obj.writeObject(this);
        this.bytesToTable(bOut.toByteArray()).printTable();

        for(edge e: neighborList){
            DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(bOut.toByteArray(), bOut.toByteArray().length,e.address,e.port);
            socket.send(pack);
        }


    }

    public void printTable(){
        System.out.println("Available Nodes:");
        for(int i = 0; i<linkList.size(); i++)
        {
            String destIP = linkList.get(i).address.toString().split("/")[1];
            int destPort = linkList.get(i).port;

            int expense = (linkList.get(i).weight);
            System.out.print("IP: " + destIP);
            System.out.print("     Port: " + destPort);
            System.out.println("      Cost: " + expense);
        }
    };


    public Vector_Table bytesToTable(byte[] inTable) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        ObjectInputStream iStream;
        Vector_Table reTable = null;    
        try {
            iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(inTable));
             reTable = (Vector_Table) iStream.readObject();
            iStream.close();
            }
         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return reTable;
    }


    public static int toInt(byte[] bytes, int offset, int dataSize) {
          int ret = 0;
          for (int i=0; i<dataSize && i+offset<bytes.length; i++) {
            ret <<= 8;
            ret |= (int)bytes[i] & 0xFF;
          }
          return ret;
        }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2846)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at Vector_Table.bytesToTable(Vector_Table.java:89)
at Vector_Table.reCalc(Vector_Table.java:30)
at vTableReceiver.run(vTableReceiver.java:37)
at router.main(router.java:26)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the exception is thrown on the 5th line down in the bytesToTable(byte[] inTable) function. ' reTable = (Vector_Table) iStream.readObject();'

Comment: So when you debug, and look at the number of bytes serialized before sending it, and the number of bytes received before trying to deserialize, you see the same byte count?

Comment: You probably need to close the ObjectOutputStream before obtaining the bytes.

Comment: Try to `flush()` the `ObjectOutputStream` after you write an object to it.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe there's an issue with me receiving the data in a fixedbuffer size in the packet (512)? Is there a way to establish a dynamic buffer size?